# Try/Catch not working with this PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script that I am updating by replacing the inline mysql queries with PDO prepared statements and queries.  When the query is correct or returns a result, it works fine.  However, when there is an error in the query statement try/catch  dies not work.  For example, I used this test code:

```
$query = $this->dbh->prepare('SELEC menu_item, hyperlink, admin FROM top_menu;');
    try
    {
            $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                    die("success");

    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die("fail");        
    }
```

The query is wrong ("SELEC" instead of "SELECT"), so the flow of the script should go into the exception/error brackets, and yet it doesn't; I keep getting "success".  I've tried catch(PDOException $e) instead of catch(Exception $e) with the exact same results.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104481/how-to-handle-pdo-exceptions), PDO won't throw exceptions unless you tell it to. Have you run:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

on the PDO object.

Answer (score -1):

For PDO's fetch() on failure FALSE is returned. No exception is thrown.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php