# PDO PHP select distinct query not working for mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've got a website that is pulling data from my MSSQL Server. I am using functions to build tables for reports. Here's what I've got:

```
function BeginTable($rowCount,$headings,$searchValue,$ReportName,$OneButton,$NewSearch)
{
    try{
    $StateSelectSQL = "select distinct State from pmdb.MaterialTracking where State is not null";
    var_dump($StateSelectSQL);echo " What!<br>";

    $getSelect = $conn->query($StateSelectSQL);
    var_dump($getSelect);echo " When!<br>";

    $StateSelectNames = $getSelect->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($StateSelectNames);echo " Where!<br>";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Something went wrong";
        die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
    }
```

I tried this too:

```
    try{
        $StateSelectSQL = "select distinct State from pmdb.MaterialTracking where State is not null";
        var_dump($StateSelectSQL);echo " What!<br>";

         $getSelect = $conn->prepare($StateSelectSQL);
         $getSelect->execute();

        //$getSelect = $conn->query($StateSelectSQL);
        //var_dump($getSelect);echo " When!<br>";

        $StateSelectNames = $getSelect->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($StateSelectNames);echo " Where!<br>";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Something went wrong<br>";
        die( print_r( $e->getMessage()));
    }
```

The second and third `var_dump`'s never show anything and the rest of the code (not shown here) doesn't get run. If I comment out the `$getSelect` and `$StateSelectNames` lines (with the `var_dump`'s under them) then everything else works.

Here is my DBConn.php file that is `included` above the `Function`:

```
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username,$password);
    //set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

What is wrong with the line `$getSelect = $conn->query($StateSelectSQL);` I can't figure it out. I tried using it later in my `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($conn->query($StateSelectSQL) as $StateName)
```

But that doesn't work either. It again stops at this line and doesn't go any further. The only thing I can think of is that my SQL is messed up, but when I run it in SSMS it works fine!

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out after pulling my hair out all day! I had to `include` my DBConn.php inside the `function`. After this it worked. I don't know why that mattered since it is `included` at the beginning of the file. If there is anyone who can explain why that is i'd be grateful!

It now looks like this:

```
function BeginTable($rowCount,$headings,$searchValue,$ReportName,$OneButton,$NewSearch)
{
    try{
        include("DBConn.php");
        $SelectSQL = "select distinct State from pmdb.MaterialTracking where State is not null order by State";            

        $getSelect = $conn->prepare($SelectSQL);

        $getSelect->execute();

        $StateSelectNames = $getSelect->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Something went wrong<br>";
            die( print_r( $e->getMessage()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try preparing and executing your SQL before using fetchAll. Also consider enabling exception mode if you haven't already and wrapping your statement in a try catch - this should flag any issues (e.g. your applications database user not having permission to access the schema, or syntax error etc)

Exceptions:

[See this stack overflow post for info about how to enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2104519/1266457)

And for your code:

```
try { 
    $sql = "
    SELECT DISTINCT State
      FROM pmdb.MaterialTracking
     WHERE State IS NOT NULL
    ";

    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    $rowset = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($rowset);

} catch PDOException($err) {
    echo "Something went wrong".
    echo $err;
}
```

Comment: I added the try catch around it (see above), but still only gets to the first `var_dump` then nothing after that! It doesn't throw an error.